# Scrapy shell against a local file

Tags: python, shell, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Before Scrapy 1.0, I could've run the Scrapy Shell against a local file quite simply:

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
```

After upgrading to 1.0.3, it started to throw an error:

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
2015-10-12 15:32:59 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: scrapybot)
2015-10-12 15:32:59 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2015-10-12 15:32:59 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/shell.py", line 50, in run
    spidercls = spidercls_for_request(spider_loader, Request(url),
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 24, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 59, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: index.html
```

Is this behavior intended or is this a bug in Scrapy Shell?

---

As a workaround, I can use an absolute path to the file in a "file" URL scheme:

```
$ scrapy shell file:////absolute/path/to/index.html
```

which is, obviously, much less convenient and easy.

Comment: Scrapy is already on track to treat `scrapy shell index.html` as `scrapy shell http://index.html/`. https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1498
For your convenience you can change your workaround to `scrapy shell file://$PWD/index.html` on *nix systems.

Comment: @digenishjkl thanks for the link to the changeset and the shortcut for the nix systems. I guess I should create an issue at scrapy github issue tracker so that we can get that "convenience" back.

Comment: Okay, created an issue in the Scrapy github issue tracker: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1550.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** for Scrapy >=1.1, *this is a built-in feature*, you can do:

```
scrapy shell file:///path/to/file.html
```

---

**Old answer:**

As per discussion in [Running scrapy shell against a local file](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1550), the relevant change was introduced by [this commit](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/9cbbfd8b04835c40568b687ef8b13d901db988cb). There was a [Pull Request](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1579) for this issue created *to make Scrapy shell open local files again* and, it is planned to be a part of Scrapy 1.1.

Comment: With Scrapy 1.5.0, I did `scrapy shell file:///path/to/file.html`. Also, I can put the same `file:///path/to/file.html` in the `start_urls`

Answer (score 4):

For Scrapy==2.5.1 you can run the Scrapy Shell against a local file like this:

If the file is in the same directory, use a "./" before your file name, like this:

```
scrapy shell ./file.html
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: invalid hostname: .\test.html`

Comment: @cikatomo Is it possible that you used a backslash, when you should have used a forwardslash? Or, maybe you're using a version other than 2.5.x?

Answer (score 2):

With following configuration

- MacOS X
- Scrapy 1.6.0

what worked for me is going with `scrapy shell ./index.html` with `index.html` being in the root folder of your scrapy generated project

Comment: Exactly, as easy as it sounds. Scrapy 2.4.1 gives a nice `DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET file:///path/to/the/file/index.html> (referer: None)`.